# Matrices, eigenvectors, operators

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$\ B = (v_{1},v_{2},v_{3})$ - basis of the vector space $V$ 
$\ U = (u_{1},u_{2},u_{3})$ - vectors set from the space $V$ 
$F$ - linear operator in $V$ space and: 
$\ Fu_1 = 2u_1 + u_2$    
$\ Fu_2 = 2u_2 + u_3 $   
$\ Fu_3 = 2u_2 $

Find matrices $\ M^U_U (F) $ and $\ M^B_B (F) $ If you know:

$\ M_B^U(\operatorname{Id})= \begin{bmatrix} 1&1&-1\\1&2&-1\\2&3&-1\end{bmatrix} $

Does there exist a base of the space $V$ that consists of eigenvectors of operator $F$?

---

So I think that 
$\ M^U_U (F) = \begin{bmatrix} 2&1&0\\0&2&1\\0&0&2\end{bmatrix} $
and
$\ M^B_B (F) =  M^U_B (I)* M^U_U (F)* M^U_B (I)$
Is it correct? 
I don't know how to do the second part.

Answer (score 1):

For finding $M^U_U (F)$, remember that the first *column* is equal to $Fu_1$ represented as coordinates in U; it looks like you did *rows* instead, and additionally there is a typo in the third row.

The equation for $M^B_B (F)$ is also close but not quite correct.  When checking, ask yourself, if I were to "process" a certain vector through both sides, would I get the same result?  I.e., if $v$ is some vector for which it is reasonable to do so, does $(M^B_B (F))v =  (M^U_B (I)* M^U_U (F)* M^U_B (I))v$?  Remember to think of $M^U_B (I)$ as the *transition matrix* which takes a vector represented in terms of B and returns a vector represented in terms of U.

For determining if the eigenvectors of F are a basis for V, remember that any set of $dim(V)$ linearly independent vectors will be a basis for V; in this case, $dim(V) = order(B) = 3$.  So, you have to determine whether or not there are 3 linearly independent eigenvectors for F.  (Remember that there will generally be infinitely many eigenvectors, but most of them will be scalar multiples of each other).